# Is it possible to create a Sass Function for getting attribute from class name

Tags: css, sass

I am using HTML dividers like this

```
<div class="divider-90"></div>
<div class="divider-180"></div>
```

and

```
.divider-90 {
   height: 90px;
   width: 100%;
}
.divider-180 {
   height: 180px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

instead of margins on elements.
I want to create a function that generates the div height depending on the class name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: im not sure about sass being able to do this, but css for sure can't. javascript can do this easy

Comment: Why aren't you using margins for this?

Comment: I use this technique to maintain some consistency on different screen sizes because when I use 'margins' i have to change the margin of each section on the entire website. That's why I started using this, ex: for different spacing in 3 screens I use
`<div class="divider-sm-90 divider-md-180 divider-lg-270"></div>`. @BenM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SASS` generates CSS, and with CSS you can't have dynamic class name, SASS won't be able to do it, but you so something like this (i personally don't like this solution):

```
@for $i from 1 through 1000{
    .divider-#{$i} { 
       height: #{$i}px;
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I personally don't like this solution because it will blow your CSS file size, and so it will takes a lot longer to be loaded and parsed, so please, consider using some "chunk based" version, something like every `10px` instead every `1px`

If you really really need this functionality, i think the best solution will be to use some JS script do generate this `height` automatically when the page is loaded

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I agree about the bad practice of this, but I have modified it so it doesn't generate as much, but only up to about 100 rows, which is acceptable to me. I use most of these classes anyway